# d3.js bar chart resize after changing the data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to resize the bar chart after changing the data. The axis are resizing but the columns are staying the same size. i would like that the columns get wider.

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ufqead6r/

Comment: It is advisable to keep the relevant parts of your code in your question along with any external source repositories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just forgot to change `x` and `width` in your update function:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
  return x(d.elem);
})
.attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/ufqead6r/1/